# Scala параметры с двоеточием при вызове метода

Tags: scala

```
final def apply(block: => Result): Action[AnyContent] =
    apply(BodyParsers.utils.ignore(AnyContentAsEmpty: AnyContent))(_ => block)
```

Кто-нибуть знает что здесь означает `AnyContentAsEmpty: AnyContent` ? AnyContentAsEmpty я так понимаю это объект, который передается в BodyParsers.utils.ignore...?  Даже не знаю как гуглить это AnyContentс двоеточием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется **ascription**.

Используется когда ты хочешь "поднять" тип до родительского. Пример аскрипции при инициализации:

```
// some имеет тип Some[Int]
val some = Some(43)
// some имеет тип Option[Int]
val some: Option[Int] = Some(43)
// вот тут аскрипция - и some имеет тип Option[Int]
val some = Some(43): Option[Int]
```

Ещё используют при вызове функции - как твоём примере. Дело в том, что функция `ignore` дженерик, т.е. её параметр типа `А` инициализируется типом из аргумента. От этого зависит тип который она вернёт.

```
BodyParsers.utils.ignore(AnyContentAsEmpty)
// res1: play.api.mvc.BodyParser[play.api.mvc.AnyContentAsEmpty.type]
BodyParsers.utils.ignore(AnyContentAsEmpty: AnyContent)
//res0: play.api.mvc.BodyParser[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]
```

Вот другой часто используемый пример -

вот так - НЕ скомпилируется

```
val list = List(1)

list.foldLeft(Right(0))( (accumulator, currentNum) => {
  if (currentNum == 0) Left(new ArithmeticException)
  else accumulator.right.map(_ + currentNum)
})
```

Из-за того что я передал `Right(0)` в первые скобки - то тип `accumulator` стал `Right[Int]`, и вся функция ждёт `Right[Int]`.

А если я  "подниму" тип до `Either` с помощью аскрипции, то могу в функции возвращать и `Right` и `Left`:

```
list.foldLeft(Right(0): Either[Exception, Int])( (accumulator, currentNum) => {
  if (currentNum == 0) Left(new ArithmeticException)
  else accumulator.right.map(_ + currentNum)
})
```

---

Ссылки:
[дока](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#ascription),
[стековерфлоу на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087250/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-ascriptions-in-scala).